# How to make hyperlinks show up properly in MS Word for files created in other word processors?

Tags: microsoft-word, compatibility, microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink, word-processing

In my job, I am often sent articles created in a variety of word processors, which I open and edit in Word 2013. However, compatibility-wise, of course they don't play very well together.

There's no heavy formatting involved, but I've been having major, persistent issues viewing hyperlinks in these articles.

1. One person writes in Pages (Mac) and saves as .docx. The hyperlinks in her files are always underlined but never in blue, as it happens in Word: they're black. I've also noticed that if I were to add a link to a file created by her, it shows up in black underlined text, not blue underlined as in my other files.
2. Another person sends files as .rtf - not sure what program but on a Mac. The hyperlinks in his files do **not** have different formatting than the rest of the text at all. Only when you mouse-over in Word can you see that there's a link there. When viewed on my Word 2013, hyperlinks and normal text are identical. Interestingly, in Gmail preview, the links in these files appear fine (blue, underlined) so I've been using this as a workaround. Said person has tried saving as .docx instead, but the hyperlinks didn't survive the conversion at all - they're not even there when you mouse over where they used to be.

Is there a way for me (rather than these two) to automatically change these files upon receipt to ones where hyperlinks appear normally, in different color and underlined?

Case #1 is bearable, but #2 has been a pain for a while now.

Example file of case #2 (contains only one hyperlink): http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=45065577867642123191

Comment: Could you post a small example of case #2 ?

Comment: Happily, but not sure what to show here - if it's the actual hyperlinks not being in different format, here you go: http://postimg.org/image/rh7gm4k3f/ (the popup appears when hovering over Further Adventures in Finance and Felony, which is where the hyperlink is).

Comment: I was asking for an actual example file that I could study. Maybe two of them : docx for case #1 and rtf for case #2. No point in giving large files.

Comment: @bibadia: Seemed like a great idea but it doesn't work, sadly. I also tried fiddling with the options... still nothing. It's as if the format of non-formatted hyperlinks is part of the embedded style but Autoformat doesn't override it. I tried converting to .docx first, then autoformatting and autoformatting without converting. No luck.

Comment: @harrymc: Just edited the post with a short example.

Comment: There is nothing on case 2's link.

Comment: Incidentally for anyone looking at this question, the problem with the sample .docx file I exported from Mac Pages (v. 5.6.2) is that the style of the display text is named "Hyperlink.0" rather than "Hyperlink". Whether this is the same problem that the OP has encountered or the only problem with Pages exports I cannot tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have studied the example file and I think I have understood the root of the
problem : The RTF format has hyperlink fields but does not have the Hyperlink style. Only more evolved document formats have this style : DOC, DOCX and DOCM.

The hyperlink fields in the RTF document are defined correctly,
but with the Normal style rather than with the Hyperlink style.
Unfortunately, Word cannot automatically correct this problem.

The solution I used to correct the example file was :

1. Save the RTF file as DOCM so it will have a Hyperlink style
   (DOCM is just the same as DOCX except that macros are allowed)
2. Run a VBA macro that sets the style of all hyperlink fields to Hyperlink

The VBA macro I used is listed below :

```
Sub hyper()
For Each oHyperlink In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
    oHyperlink.Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Hyperlink")
Next oHyperlink
ActiveDocument.Range.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

The advantage of this solution is that it assigns the real Hyperlink style to all
hyperlink fields. This is better than only doing cosmetic changes such as to the
font color and underline.

Comment: Thanks, this macro worked great for case #2 but interestingly, not at all for #1 - documents created in Pages. Also - is it possible to alter it with commands to change the default font and font size too?

Comment: One can do anything wanted with `oHyperlink.Range`, not only setting the style. Case #1: you could post an example,  but maybe first [Enable view field codes](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T006080_Tools_to_View_Field_Codes.html) to see how/if Pages did create these fields.

Answer (score 0):

If all the hyperlinks are actually hyperlinks (not just text), then

Fret no more my friend

10 easy steps await you.

Try this:

1. Press `Alt+F9` in the document you want to see the change in (this will transform and reveal all the hyperlinks, nothing to worry about).
2. Press `Ctrl+H` to open `Find and Replace`.
3. Type `^d hyperlink` in the `Find` box.
4. Move the cursor and select the `Replace with` box, but don't type anything.
5. Click on the `More` button below the `Replace with` field.
6. Click on the `Format` button below the other options which you just revealed.
7. Click on `Style`.
8. Select `Hyperlink` from the list (press `H` on your keyboard to find it more easily) and click on `OK`.
9. Click on `Replace All` and voila! 'tis all done.
10. Close the `Find and Replace` window and press `Alt+F9`.

TIP: If you don't want to do this every time for every document, you can create a Macro function and place it on the Ribbon. Just a mouse click from then on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Seyyed. This sounds like something that should be working but it doesn't, and I think I know why: 

In the "Find style" popup, the Description of Hyperlink in the "bad" document says "Font color: Hyperlink" while the same box in a normal document created by me it says "Font color: Blue". 

So, as I suspected, it is a matter of the Style information contained in these specific files themselves. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Too large for a comment (which it should be because this is not well-tested and may not do what you want).

If AutoFormat does not do enough (as per our conversation in Comments), I think you will need to do a fair amount to each hyperlink, i.e.

- ensure it has been recognised as a Hyperlink by Word (in which case
  you should be able to see a { HYPERLINK } field code if you use
  Alt-F9)
- apply the Hyperlink character style to the result of the HYPERLINK
  field
- re-apply character formatting to the HYPERLINK field result to fix
  the damage that imposing the Hyperlink style can do

If the imported text contains a number of hyperlinks, doing all that will probably be quite tedious, so the following piece of VBA is intended to fix up hyperlinks in the body of the currently active Word document.

It will only detect things that Word thinks are hyperlinks (not necessarily everything you expect).

I would suggest that if possible you open any imported texts as separate documents in the first instance, then run this code. That should minimise undesirable side effects.

The thing about the Hyperlink character style is that it applies the "Default Paragraph Font" which may not have the same properties (e.g. size etc.) as the existing text. Even if you modify the style to use "Underlying Properties" it may change text size and so on. So what I have done here is to look at the properties of the first character in the "display text" for the Hyperlink, and re-apply it to the whole display text after applying the Hyperlink style.

But if you are applying your own paragraph styles to the imported text, it is more likely that text styled with the Hyperlink style will do what you want anyway, so you might be able to remove that bit of VBA.

If you need to look for hyperlinks in other "stories" in the document such as text boxes, headers/footers etc., then you will definitely need more.

```
Private Type AutoFormatOptions
  bAutoFormatApplyBulletedLists As Boolean
  bAutoFormatApplyFirstIndents As Boolean
  bAutoFormatApplyHeadings As Boolean
  bAutoFormatApplyLists As Boolean
  bAutoFormatApplyOtherParas As Boolean
  bAutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces As Boolean
  bAutoFormatMatchParentheses As Boolean
  bAutoFormatPlainTextWordMail As Boolean
  bAutoFormatPreserveStyles As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceFractions As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceOrdinals As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceQuotes As Boolean
  bAutoFormatReplaceSymbols As Boolean
End Type
Sub fixUpHyperlinks()

Dim afo As AutoFormatOptions

Dim f As Word.Font

Dim h As Word.Hyperlink
' Save existing autoformat options

With Application.Options
  afo.bAutoFormatApplyBulletedLists = .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists
  afo.bAutoFormatApplyFirstIndents = .AutoFormatApplyFirstIndents
  afo.bAutoFormatApplyHeadings = .AutoFormatApplyHeadings
  afo.bAutoFormatApplyLists = .AutoFormatApplyLists
  afo.bAutoFormatApplyOtherParas = .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas
  afo.bAutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces = .AutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces
  afo.bAutoFormatMatchParentheses = .AutoFormatMatchParentheses
  afo.bAutoFormatPlainTextWordMail = .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail
  afo.bAutoFormatPreserveStyles = .AutoFormatPreserveStyles
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes = .AutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceFractions = .AutoFormatReplaceFractions
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceOrdinals = .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals
  afo.bAutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis = .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceQuotes = .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes
  afo.bAutoFormatReplaceSymbols = .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols
End With
On Error GoTo cleanup

' set everything the way we want

With Application.Options
  ' all false
  .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists = False
  .AutoFormatApplyFirstIndents = False
  .AutoFormatApplyHeadings = False
  .AutoFormatApplyLists = False
  .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas = False
  .AutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces = False
  .AutoFormatMatchParentheses = False
  .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail = False
  .AutoFormatPreserveStyles = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceFractions = False
  ' except this one
  .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = True
  .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals = False
  .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = False
  .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols = False
End With

With ActiveDocument

  ' Apply the selected formats
  .Kind = wdDocumentNotSpecified
  .Content.AutoFormat

  ' Now apply the Hyperlink style to all Hyperlink field result ranges

  For Each h In .Hyperlinks
    With .Range.Fields(1).Result
      If .Characters.Count >= 1 Then
        ' Remove the following line if the Hyperlink style works for you
        Set f = .Characters(1).Font.Duplicate
        ' Apply the Hyperlink style
        .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHyperlink).NameLocal
        ' Remove the following 2 lines if the Hyperlink style works for you
        Set .Font = f
        set f = Nothing
      End If
    End With
  Next

End With

cleanup:
' restore the original settings

With Application.Options
  .AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists = afo.bAutoFormatApplyBulletedLists
  .AutoFormatApplyFirstIndents = afo.bAutoFormatApplyFirstIndents
  .AutoFormatApplyHeadings = afo.bAutoFormatApplyHeadings
  .AutoFormatApplyLists = afo.bAutoFormatApplyLists
  .AutoFormatApplyOtherParas = afo.bAutoFormatApplyOtherParas
  .AutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces = afo.bAutoFormatDeleteAutoSpaces
  .AutoFormatMatchParentheses = afo.bAutoFormatMatchParentheses
  .AutoFormatPlainTextWordMail = afo.bAutoFormatPlainTextWordMail
  .AutoFormatPreserveStyles = afo.bAutoFormatPreserveStyles
  .AutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceFarEastDashes
  .AutoFormatReplaceFractions = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceFractions
  .AutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceHyperlinks
  .AutoFormatReplaceOrdinals = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceOrdinals
  .AutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis = afo.bAutoFormatReplacePlainTextEmphasis
  .AutoFormatReplaceQuotes = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceQuotes
  .AutoFormatReplaceSymbols = afo.bAutoFormatReplaceSymbols
End With

'    Application.Options.AutoFormatApplyBulletedLists
'    Selection.Document.Kind = wdDocumentNotSpecified
'    Selection.Range.AutoFormat
End Sub
```